# How to use react hook form 7 with MUI switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

When using react-hook-form with MUI switch, the switch doesn't display the initial value on page load, even though the value is set to true. It seems to be a display issue though, because submitting the form with buttons untouched yields `true` for the switches that have a `true` value defined. Also, clicking these buttons (showing false) once does nothing (they stay on the left), clicking them a second time will actually toggle them on again.

Setting initial values using hook (works for all other field types):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userProfile) {
    setValue('firstname', userProfile.firstname);
    setValue('lastname', userProfile.lastname);
    setValue('show_profile', userProfile.show_profile || false);
  }
}, [userProfile]);
```

The switch is implemented like this:

```
<FormControlLabel
    control={<Switch {...register('show_profile')} />}
    label="Profil öffentlich (beinhaltet Vor- und Nachname)"
/>
```

This in turn is a checkbox component that works perfectly fine:

```
<FormControlLabel
    control={
      <Checkbox
        {...register('steuerbescheinigung')}
        name="steuerbescheinigung"
      />
    }
    label="Steuerbescheinigung benötigt?"
  />
```

How to use `react-hook-form` with MUI Switch and set initial values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/).

> React Hook Form embraces uncontrolled components and native inputs,
> however it's hard to avoid working with external controlled component
> such as React-Select, AntD and MUI. This wrapper component will make
> it easier for you to work with them.

You need to use the `Controller` component from `react-hook-form` to wrap your `Switch` component and pass the `value` and `onChange` props from the field object.

For example:

```
<Controller
  name="show_profile"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={<Switch checked={value} onChange={onChange} />}
      label="Profil öffentlich (beinhaltet Vor- und Nachname)"
    />
  )}
/>;
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-dream-s242ty?file=/Demo.tsx).

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thank you very much! I didn't really look into it as all other MUI components work uncontrolled.

Comment: It's my pleasure. I'm glad it works fine. - @Daniel